# VueJS / NuxtJS Access to object

Tags: vue.js, oop, nuxt.js, vue-router

How can I access to company object ?
I tried  `this.$data.company.id;`

[image]

Comment: please share the code as text

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim
`this.$axios
      .$post(`/api/dashboard/switch_company/${company.slug}`)
      .then(() => {
        this.$router.push({ name: "company_dashboard" });
      });`
when I redirect to campany_dashboard, I want to access to that response !

Comment: Edit your question rather than posting it as a one-liner. Also, please show more code.

Answer (score 0):

If that component is in the root of nuxt you can do this

```html
<company-dashboard-layout ref="dashboard" />
```

```js
const component = window.$nuxt.$children
      .find(({ $refs }) => $refs.dashboard) // same name as ref

console.log(component.$data) // {company: {id:"572...."} }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a lot of code shown here but you can probably access it with

```js
this.company.id
```

Inside of your `CompanyDashboardLayout`.

If you want to access it in your browser through the devtools, you can use

```js
$vm0.company.id
```